# CSS Random space between elements

Tags: html, css

i've recently started working on my own video player for fun however, I can't seem to tell where this space between my video element and my div elements is coming from here is an image of what i'm referring to. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDknT.png (Can't post an image so I had to post a link to it)

My styling:

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div#player_container
{
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

video
{
    background-color: #000;
}

div#player_controls
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #383B42;
}

div#player_seekbar
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #3066DB;
    z-index: 2;
}

div#player_buffered_bar
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is my html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Player - Version: 0.1a</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="player_container">

            <video id="player" width="1280" height="720">

                <source src="test_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="test_video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.

            </video>

            <div id="player_controls">

                <div id="player_seekbar"></div>

                <div id="player_buffered_bar"></div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome it looks ok (no white bar)

Comment: How can you call that random? It is **every** reload on the same place...

Comment: @Bondye I call it 'Random' because it is a space that I didn't intend to make so thus I call it 'Random', by the way that was a pointless post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<video>` is a inline element which has a vertical-align by default (`baseline`).

You can either `vertical-align` it with `middle` or easier make all `<video>`s block elements:

```
video {
   display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Atup4/

Answer (score 0):

**OR USE NEGATIVE MARGIN**

```
div#player_controls
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin:-5px;
    background-color: #383B42;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VOXRAZR/y4H2Z/

Answer (score 0):

Images and videos are by default inline elements, so line-height is enabled, leaving this white space below them. You just have to **make theme display: block**, and the white space will disappear.

http://dabblet.com/gist/8580610c930fee1d05d6

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract the margin a bit:

```
div#player_seekbar
{
    position: absolute;
       margin-top: -4px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #3066DB;
    z-index: 2;
}

div#player_buffered_bar
{
    position: absolute;
       margin-top: -4px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    z-index: 1;
}
```