# Extra Spacing Image Responsive Website

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a responsive website and my there is extra space after my main image:http://juddbuilders.com/www/

I cannot figure out what is causing this extra space. Even if I take out the nav/all class styles on the photo the space remains between between the photo and   .

Could someone please help me? Thank you!

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
 <img class="fluid-img" src="images/header-photo.jpg" alt="Plan Your Home" width="1140"    height="400"/>
```

Comment: can u add jsfiddle demo?

Comment: I've basically answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931274/css-random-space-between-elements/24931436. Just apply it to your `<img>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to ur CSS.

```
.fluid-img{
  display:block;
}
```